# PostgreSQL subselect problem

Tags: database, postgresql

When I try to do the select statement, I always get the following error:

*ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*

Only if there's only one result, it works. Why and how to fix?

```
SELECT name from person p where 
id = ( select prs from leader 
where age(leader.lastcourse) > '1 year');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to assign one particular ID from a select that seems to be returning multiple ID's.  OrbMan's solution will take the first ID, randomly, from the subquery.  If you want ALL ID's that meet the subquery condition,

```
SELECT name from person p where  
id IN ( select prs from leader  
where age(leader.lastcourse) > '1 year');
```

Mark's approach to use a JOIN rather than subquery also works.

Comment: Why should there be a 'top 1'?
Works only without it.

Comment: @melbic: Because I made a cut and paste error :-)  Fixed the post.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to say that an integer is equal or not equal to a result set containing two rows. To do what you want you can choose between IN, EXISTS, or a JOIN. Here's how you can do it with a join:

```
SELECT name
FROM person p
JOIN leader
ON p.id = leader.prs
where age(leader.lastcourse) > '1 year'
```